# Communication range inside the photon sphere of a Black hole

Tags: black-holes, spacetime, thought-experiment

Alice and Bob are positioned diametrically opposite to each other, just a little bit inside the photon sphere of a huge (*great mass*) non-rotating black hole (BH). Both of them can communicate via light signals using a Morse lamp. The light, since it happens to be originating inside the photon sphere, would in-spiral into and beyond the horizon of the BH. This allows some time for Alice and Bob to communicate. However, beyond a radius, **r**, they would not be able to do the same since their light signals would have already been doomed.

What would be the limits of range of **r** for communication (or range of communication)?
How would this change if the BH was a rotating one?

It is obvious that the upper limit would be just a little bit lesser that the radius of the photon sphere, i.e., $r<{3GM}$ , with $c=1$. The lower limit cannot be the Schwarzschild radius due to the fact that the light signals in-spiral faster than Alice or Bob does.

Comment: By positioning Alice and Bob here and not allowing them to move, how are you not moving them faster than light?

Comment: They are not being held static, they too are moving, slowly into the BH's horizon. Since the BH here is a large one with a great mass, the curvature in small and hence the tidal forces acting on Alice an Bob are small. So no one is moving faster than the speed of light.